# Switch keys and value and Preserve entries with no value

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have this `array`:

```
'tab1' => '',
'tab2' => '',
'tab3' => 'active'
```

I want to do `array_flip` to swap the keys with the values, but the entries with an empty value are not kept.

How do I let PHP assign integer keys for me (like with an indexed array)?

Thanks

**Edit:**

To clarify things a bit, this is what I want:

```
0 => 'tab1'
1 => 'tab2'
'active' => 'tab3'
```

Comment: you cant have empty or duplicate key's, so what is the desired outcome?

Comment: Is it possible that you need `array_key` function instead?

Comment: @sectus if I use `array_key`, then how will I be able to preserve the "active" entry?

Comment: @jasonszhao, I do not know because I do not know what do you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly through `array_flip` it's not possible. I think you want like this:-

```
<?php

$array1 = array('tab1' => '','tab2' => '','tab3' => 'active');

$array2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $key =>$value){
    if(empty($value)){ // Or $value ==''
        $array2[] = $key;
    }else{
        $array2[$value] = $key;
    }

}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($array2);die;
?>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/79ge6z

Comment: It's better to use one of php fiddle services instead of screenshots. For example: http://3v4l.org/vUtj9

Comment: Thanks @anantkumarsingh. But perhaps using `empty()`?

Comment: I hope you get your solution.

Comment: Yes, @anantkumarsingh I just wanted to see if others had something to add